# How to fail TFS deploy based on bat/exe output on target machine?

Tags: tfs, msdeploy

we are trying to fail deploy based on whether site is up or down on the target machine. To check site status we will be either using batch file or managed exe.
How to fail TFS deploy based on bat/exe output on target machine?

Comment: more info:
Controller/agent is on one machince and project is hosted on two different machines(say A and B). We need to fail deploy based on the site status on two machines(A and B). for example if site is in "started" state on machine A, then we donot want to proceed with deploy.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [PowerShell on Target Machines](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/build/steps/deploy/powershell-on-target-machines) task to check the site status, if the site is stop, fail this task.